# Is using generic interface justifies using another marker interfaces?

Tags: c#, oop

Let's assume I have an interface that has some method parametherized with another interface:

```
interface IFeature<T> where T : IFeatureParameters
{
    CustomObject Apply(CustomObject obj, T featureParameters);
}
```

But features are so much different that there is nothing common in their parameters so **IFeatureParameters** interface is in fact marker interface. It just forces developers in future to create **Feature** and **FeatureParameters** implementations in pairs.

As far as I googled, marker interfaces are considered to have no reasons to exist in custom code.

Is it suitable to use marker interfaces in my case? If not, what may substitute it?

Comment: If `IFeatureParameters` has neither properties nor methods, why does `Apply` even care?

Comment: Is `IFeature` itself even meaningful? Without the interface it essentially reduces to `object Apply(object, object)`, which suggests absolutely nothing about how it should be implemented or used. If used only in a few places (or even just one) it sounds like the sort of thing a single well placed `Func` might also do.

Comment: @JeroenMoster, fair enough. 
The reason I wanted to implement it is to create some kind of "uses-a" relationship between `IFeature` and `IFeatureParameters` and bind them together. And to force others who write implementations of those interfaces to implement *both* interfaces for one purpose. To avoid situations when `OneFeatureParamers` are passed into `AnotherFeature.Apply`

Comment: @ThomasSchremser, you're right, it has not. But its implementation would. And the interface is just used for the purposes descriped in the comment above.

Comment: An alternative would be to inject `OneFeatureParameters` into the constructor of `OneFeature` (and likewise for any other pair of implementations). It does mean that any single instance of `OneFeature` cannot switch from one instance of `OneFeatureParameters` to another instance of `OneFeatureParameters`. Is that acceptable?

Comment: @RuudHelderman, Nope, not at all. And anyway, how do you imagine generalization of your idea using interfaces? Post an answer, please.

Comment: @SviatoslavIakovlev `And to force others who write implementations of those interfaces to implement both interfaces for one purpose` heard of YAGNI principle?

Comment: @zaitsman. Yes. But i guess it's a good subject for another talk. Here I'm just interested if it is worthy to use marker interfaces if I have such needs or not.

Comment: @SviatoslavIakovlev No, specifically because `You ain't gonna need it' :) Which is why I quoted it. What is the value of your interfaces? `Forcing` people to do something for no reason but that you want to is not a good enough reason. Maintainability of that code just dropped, and that had 0 benefits. That is why `marker interfaces are considered to have no reasons to exist in custom code`. Specifically in C#, where you have the full power of reflection at your disposal.

Comment: @zaitsman, ok, now it sounds very reasonable. How do you think, should I leave the question as it is or just delete it?

Comment: That's up to you to decide, if you're satisfied with the comments you received here.

Comment: @zaitsman OP is just using static strong typing to enforce a contract between pairs of classes (features and feature parameters). Nothing wrong with that. Some may consider it overkill, but why call it a YAGNI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An interface `IFeatureParameters` has no added value here. Whether or not a class (or whatever type you like) is a valid type to pass parameters to a feature, is entirely determined by the feature implementation. 
Every time a developer makes a new implementation of interface `IFeature`, they will specify explicitly what is the correct parameter type, by filling in the type variable `T`. 
That is enough to ensure no 'alien' types will be passed into an implementation of method `Apply`.

Here is a simple example.

```
public class FeatureParametersA
{
    public string SomeText;
}

public class FeatureParametersB
{
    public int SomeNumber;
}
```

I could have made these classes implement an interface `IFeatureParameters`, but that is not required.

```
public interface IFeature<T>
{
    CustomObject Apply(CustomObject obj, T par);
}

public class FeatureA : IFeature<FeatureParametersA>
{
    public CustomObject Apply(CustomObject obj, FeatureParametersA par);
    {
        obj.Add(par.SomeText);
        return obj;
    }
}

public class FeatureB : IFeature<FeatureParametersB>
{
    public CustomObject Apply(CustomObject obj, FeatureParametersB par);
    {
        obj.Add(par.SomeNumber.ToString());
        return obj;
    }
}
```

Notice how each class has its own dedicated implementation of `Apply`, specific for the related 'parameters' type.
Everything is strongly typed, so the compiler will prevent anyone from trying to pass the wrong type into `Apply`.

For completeness:

```
public class CustomObject
{
    public void Add(string s) { _sb.AppendLine(s); }
    private StringBuilder _sb = new StringBuilder();
}
```

Comment: Ok, but to finally catch the idea (maybe it's not fully related to the question, but still): Imagine my next step is to create a pipeline of applying those features. For those purposes I create new interface IFeaturePipeline which contains something like IList<IFeature<===>> Features { get; } . Which type should be used instead of ===? Just object? And so I do not restrict it anyhow at compile time?

Comment: Generics are resolved in compile time. You can make a list of `IFeature<T>`, but that means `T` is the same for the entire list. If you need a list of features with varying implementations, then there are two possibilities. (1) Don't use generics; use interfaces instead. (2) Wrap `IFeature<T>` in a class that hides away `T`. That implies you will not be able to access method `Apply` through the pipeline.